# provisionner vs. approvisionner vs. s'approvisionner

Tags: différence

How do *provisionner* vs. *approvisionner* vs. *s'approvisionner* differ? I know that

- *approvisionner* = [*ad-* + *provisionner*](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/approvisionner)
- *s'approvisionner* is the reflexive verb of *approvisionner*.

I Googled to find [merely one post on *provisionner* vs. *approvisionner*](https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/approvisionner-provisionner.2101293/post-10514280). But it does not showcase other differences, or moot *s'approvisionner*.

Comment: Hi 1147844, bienvenue sur French Language SE.  STP include the dictionary definitions you found so you can show us where you are stuck.  I also encourage you to see the [help].

Comment: @user1147844 a quick dictionary lookup will give you the answer. Googling "X vs Y" is probably not the best, and by no means the only option when looking for the definition of X and Y, however close they seem...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**provisionner** is presently used in financial domain and means that,
in a company's accounts (financial records), an amount of money is kept in case of a possible future loss (example: *The insurance company made a provision against claims over alleged pension fraud*).

**approvisionner** means to supply (as in following example : *Who is supplying the rebels with guns and ammunition?*)

**s'approvisionner** means to stock up things for own usage (e.g.*to stock up on firewood for the winter*)

Comment: *Provisionner* is listed under 9 different fields in the Grand dictionnaire terminologique : army, insurance, IT, telecom, etc... https://vitrinelinguistique.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/resultats-de-recherche?tx_solr%5Bq%5D=provisionner&tx_solr%5Bfilter%5D%5B1%5D=type_stringM%3Agdt&tx_solr%5Bfilter%5D%5B2%5D=terme%3A1

Comment: @guillaume31 : in the referenced fields, the definition of "provisionner" corresponds to funds kept for potential loss.  In the army field, "provisionnements navals" seems dubious.